# Integrate Vim-R-plugin with remote ssh-byobu session?

Tags: vim, ssh, tmux, byobu, vim-r

I am following the inspiring example [here](http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/programming-in-r/vim-r) to setup `Vim` for `R` development. One difference is that I am running Vim and R on a remote server via `ssh` session. And this `ssh` starts `byobu`, which has `tmux` started automatically whenever I login. What I want is to make an `Vim-R-Dev` command/alias so that: 
After logging in with the `ssh` and `tmux` is already running, I can type `Vim-R-Dev` to open up a window with panes look like in the attached image:

> Illustration of sending R code from several vim viewports (in middle)
>   to an R session (on top right). The vim session can run on a local
>   computer, while the R session can run on the same or a remote system.
>   The snapshot also illustrates the omni completion utility of the
>   vim-r-plugin (purple box), viewing of an R function help document in a
>   separate tmux pane (bottom right) and the NERDTree file browser
>   (left).

[image: Vim-R, tmux]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while of fumbling with Vim and R, I decided to quit this approach. My feeling was that the combination is not mature enough for production. So I tried to find and found EMACS + ESS. Yes, emacs is the rival to Vim as a programmer/geek editor. And it seems I am a traitor of Vim jump to Emacs when the two are at war :-) It doesn't have to be that way.

At first I installed emacs and ess plugin/package and tried to learn the basics. I was very happy about how ESS is much more mature than vimR. And the way emacs works with packages and configuration make me much more happy than when I used Vim. This is partly because I have some basic background and was willing to deal with ELISP, the LISP programming language variant that is made for Emacs. An advice for some one have Vim skills though: You'd better off install `Evil` package from the beginning so you have the power of quick editing in Vim but the whole pack of other wonderful things, i.e. robustness, fine customization, in-place documentation. I have discussed many things about Emacs and ESS here on stackoverflow.com and at emacs.stackexchange.com too. The essential setup for R programmer is:

`Emacs, ESS, Evil, Helm*, auto-complete, auctex, polymode, r-autoyas`. Following are full list of additional packages that I installed. The one that allows me to edit and run code on remote server is called `tramp` with X forwarding. I will post more on this if there are requests.

```
  ac-ispell          0.7           installed             ispell completion source for auto-complete
  async              1.3           installed             Asynchronous processing in Emacs
  auctex             11.88.6       installed             Integrated environment for *TeX*
  auto-complete      1.5.0         installed             Auto Completion for GNU Emacs
  auto-complete-e... 0.0.7         installed             Exuberant ctags auto-complete.el source
  auto-complete-pcmp 0.0.2         installed             Provide auto-complete sources using pcomplete results
  auto-dictionary    1.1           installed             automatic dictionary switcher for flyspell
  auto-package-up... 1.4           installed             Automatically update Emacs packages.
  auto-yasnippet     0.3.0         installed             Quickly create disposable yasnippets
  bash-completion    2.0.0         installed             BASH completion for the shell buffer
  bind-key           20140601      installed             A simple way to manage personal keybindings
  bog                1.0.0         installed             Extensions for research notes in Org mode
  bongo              1.0           installed             play music with Emacs
  boon               0.1           installed             Ergonomic Command Mode for Emacs.
  bug-hunter         0.5           installed             Hunt down errors in elisp files
  calfw              1.4           installed             Calendar view framework on Emacs
  column-enforce-... 20140902.949  installed             Highlight text that extends beyond a  column
  column-marker      20121128.843  installed             Highlight certain character columns
  company            0.8.12        installed             Modular text completion framework
  ctable             20140304.1659 installed             Table component for Emacs Lisp
  ctags              1.1.1         installed             No description available.
  ctags-update       0.2.0         installed             (auto) update TAGS in parent directory using exuberant-ctags
  cython-mode        0.23.2.2      installed             Major mode for editing Cython files
  d-mode             2.0.6         installed             D Programming Language mode for (X)Emacs
  dash               2.11.0        installed             A modern list library for Emacs
  diminish           0.44          installed             Diminished modes are minor modes with no modeline display
  discover           0.3           installed             discover more of Emacs
  el-autoyas         0.5           installed             Automatically create Emacs-Lisp Yasnippets
  elpy               1.8.1         installed             Emacs Python Development Environment
  epl                71.4.8098     installed             Emacs Package Library
  ess                20150810.826  installed             Emacs Speaks Statistics
  ess-R-data-view    20130509.458  installed             Data viewer for GNU R
  ess-R-object-popup 20130302.336  installed             popup description of R object
  ess-smart-equals   20150201.2201 installed             better smart-assignment with =-key in R and S
  ess-smart-under... 20131229.1851 installed             Ess Smart Underscore
  evil               20150810.426  installed             Extensible Vi layer for Emacs.
  evil-leader        20140606.543  installed             let there be <leader>
  evil-org           20150513.1610 installed             evil keybindings for org-mode
  expand-region      20150804.2210 installed             Increase selected region by semantic units.
  f                  20150605.927  installed             Modern API for working with files and directories
  find-file-in-pr... 20150722.2347 installed             Find files in a project quickly.
  flx                20140921.739  installed             fuzzy matching with good sorting
  flx-ido            20140821.2033 installed             flx integration for ido
  ggtags             20150718.2227 installed             emacs frontend to GNU Global source code tagging system
  gh                 20150126.1125 installed             A GitHub library for Emacs
  git                20140128.241  installed             An Elisp API for programmatically using Git
  git-auto-commit... 20150404.751  installed             Emacs Minor mode to automatically commit and push
  git-commit         20150805.2024 installed             Edit Git commit messages
  git-commit-mode    1.0.0         installed             Major mode for editing git commit messages
  git-messenger      20150314.602  installed             Pop up last commit information of current line
  goto-chg           20131228.1459 installed             goto last change
  helm               20150805.54   installed             Helm is an Emacs incremental and narrowing framework
  helm-ack           20141030.526  installed             Ack command with helm interface
  helm-core          20150805.206  installed             Development files for Helm
  helm-github-stars  20150625.1523 installed             Helm integration for your starred repositories on github
  helm-mode-manager  20140224.1504 installed             Select and toggle major and minor modes with helm
  highlight-inden... 20150307.208  installed             Minor modes for highlighting indentation
  hippie-expand-s... 20130907.132  installed             Hook slime's completion into hippie-expand
  imenu-list         20150804.705  installed             Show imenu entries in a seperate buffer
  key-chord          20150808.1705 installed             map pairs of simultaneously pressed keys to commands
  latex-extra        20150806.1521 installed             Adds several useful functionalities to LaTeX-mode.
  latex-pretty-sy... 20150409.240  installed             Display many latex symbols as their unicode counterparts
  latex-preview-pane 20150519.1244 installed             Makes LaTeX editing less painful by providing a updatable preview pane
  let-alist          1.0.4         installed             Easily let-bind values of an assoc-list by their names
  log4e              20150105.505  installed             provide logging framework for elisp
  logito             20120225.1255 installed             logging library for Emacs
  magit              20150807.401  installed             A Git porcelain inside Emacs
  magit-gh-pulls     20150723.1144 installed             GitHub pull requests extension for Magit
  magit-popup        20150730.1344 installed             Define prefix-infix-suffix command combos
  makey              20131231.630  installed             interactive commandline mode
  markdown-mode      20150727.855  installed             Emacs Major mode for Markdown-formatted text files
  markdown-toc       20150715.914  installed             A simple TOC generator for markdown file
  monokai-theme      20150521.2257 installed             A fruity color theme for Emacs.
  org-ac             20140302.413  installed             Some auto-complete sources for org-mode
  org-autolist       20150118.1837 installed             Improved list management in org-mode
  pcache             20150125.1653 installed             persistent caching for Emacs
  php-auto-yasnip... 20141128.1411 installed             Creates snippets for PHP functions
  php-mode           20150729.213  installed             Major mode for editing PHP code
  pkg-info           20150517.443  installed             Information about packages
  polymode           20150729.734  installed             Versatile multiple modes with extensive literate programming support
  popup              20150626.711  installed             Visual Popup User Interface
  popup-complete     20141108.1908 installed             completion with popup
  popwin             20150315.600  installed             Popup Window Manager.
  powerline          20150628.1957 installed             Rewrite of Powerline
  powerline-evil     20140517.1    installed             Utilities for better Evil support for Powerline
  projectile         20150807.620  installed             Manage and navigate projects in Emacs easily
  pyvenv             20150503.941  installed             Python virtual environment interface
  r-autoyas          20140101.710  installed             Provides automatically created yasnippets for R function argument lists.
  real-auto-save     20150701.815  installed             Automatically save your all your buffers/files at regular intervals.
  rtags              20150804.2337 installed             No description available.
  s                  20140910.334  installed             The long lost Emacs string manipulation library.
  scala-mode2        20150617.2350 installed             Major mode for editing Scala >= 2.9
  scala-outline-p... 20150702.937  installed             scala file summary popup
  seq                20150709.1040 installed             Sequence manipulation functions
  session            20120510.1700 installed             use variables, registers and buffer places across sessions
  skeletor           20150228.1557 installed             Provides project skeletons for Emacs
  sx                 20150718.625  installed             StackExchange client. Ask and answer questions on Stack Overflow, Super User, and the likes
  twilight-anti-b... 20140810.34   installed             A soothing Emacs 24 light-on-dark theme
  undo-tree          20140509.522  installed             Treat undo history as a tree
  use-package        20150731.2330 installed             A use-package declaration for simplifying your .emacs
  which-key          20150803.1211 installed             Display available keybindings in popup
  window-purpose     20150715.439  installed             Purpose-based window management for Emacs
  with-editor        20150710.252  installed             Use the Emacsclient as $EDITOR
  yaml-mode          20141125.37   installed             Major mode for editing YAML files
  yasnippet          20150804.1120 installed             Yet another snippet extension for Emacs.
  yatemplate         20150305.1526 installed             File templates with yasnippet
  yaxception         20150105.652  installed             Provide framework about exception like Java for Elisp
  zygospore          20140703.152  installed             reversible C-x 1 (delete-other-windows)
```